# Select não carrega os options corrretamente

Tags: php, html

Bom dia Galera Dev, desde ontém me deparei como uma situação um tanto bizarra (se posso falar assim).

Eu estou utilizando php poo para carregar um select e trazendo a resposta em um while:

```
while($dados = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
    $cd_cobr = $dados["cd_tipo_cobr"];
    $ds_cobr = $dados["ds_tipo_cobr"];

    echo("<option value='$cd_cobr' selected='yes'> $ds_cobr </option>");
    echo("$cd_cobr $ds_cobr");
}
```

Já fiz dessa forma 1 milhão de vezes, mas desde ontem ele está carregando o html assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Percebam que eu mandei printar propositalmente as variáveis para ver se o valor estava correto, e está. Se eu inverto as variáveis de ordem só aparece o 'PAG'. Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui achar o problema, havia duas requisições em java/jquery que lia o select e isso estava fazendo o 'value' ficar NULL, removi uma das requisições e funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Tente dessa forma:

```
echo "<option value='", $cd_cobr , "' selected='yes'>", $ds_cobr, "</option>";
```